# ELKI showing negative values in Pair Counting Measures

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, elki

When i run some cepstral coefficient data generated from .wav
    files in ELKI wit Kmeans Algorithm k =32 and max iter=100 it gives
    negative values for the following Pair Counting Measures.
    Jaccard=-3.3627 Recall=-3.3627 Rand=-3.3627 and F1 Measure=2.8465 I
    searched somewhere for the range of these measures and they were
    (0,1). I ran this data with several other algorithms and having the
    same problem. Can anyone please interpret it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting.

Comment: Is your data available? What are your *labels*? Which version of ELKI?

Answer (score 1):

The values *should* be in the range of [0;1], but:

- only if you have complete labels (missing labels can be skipped, but I'm not sure if our implementation handles this case yet)
- the clustering must be a complete, non-overlapping, crisp partitioning

Furthermore, when clusters degenerate (depending on your data and seeding, this *may* happen with k-means) there could be empty clusters, and these again may yield undesired results with the literate implementation of these measures.

How did you label your data?

We try our best to also handle corner cases right; but we can only diagnose and fix what we have observed and can reproduce.